# Case-insensitive match in ActiveRecord with LOWER() not finding any matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to perform a case-insensitive search using activerecord. But it does not work.

this is for macos postgres server 11.11 rails 5.2.1

query:

```rb
Post.joins(:terms, :subcategory, :category).where("LOWER(terms.title) LIKE LOWER('Апелласьон')")
```

result:
two found of Post

query:

```rb
Post.joins(:terms, :subcategory, :category).where("LOWER(terms.title) LIKE LOWER('апелласьон')")
```

result:
zero found of post

Comment: Cyrillic `а` and Latin `a` are two different characters as far as Postgres is concerned unless there's a collation that fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in Postgres gives the reason. This is an encoding issue, you're using Cyrillic Letter A and Rails/Postgres is probably trying to compare it to a Basic Latin `A`, giving you unexpected results.

```
SELECT 
    ASCII(LOWER('Апелласьон')),  -- 1072
    ASCII(LOWER('апелласьон')),  -- 1072
    ASCII(LOWER('a')),           -- 97
    ASCII(LOWER('A'))            -- 97
```

---

Here are the ASCII codes for each character

https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1072

https://www.codetable.net/decimal/97

---

Someone with more knowledge of character codes in Postgres will have to give a more meaningful explanation.